# Grouping Collection separating numeric 5 from String "5"

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, advanceddatagrid

**BackGround:** I have an advanced data grid. The data provider for this ADG is an ArrayCollection. There is a grouping collection on an ID field of this AC.

Example of a couple items within this AC the AC var name is "arcTemplates":

```
(mx.collections::ArrayCollection)#0
  filterFunction = (null)
  length = 69
  list = (mx.collections::ArrayList)#1
    length = 69
    source = (Array)#2
      [0] (Object)#3
        abbreviation = "sore-throat"
        insertDate = "11/16/2009"
        name = "sore throat"
        templateID = 234
        templateType = "New Problem"
        templateTypeID = 1
     [32] (Object)#35
        abbreviation = 123
        insertDate = "03/08/2010"
        name = 123
        templateID = 297
        templateType = "New Problem"
        templateTypeID = 1
     [55] (Object)#58
        abbreviation = 1234
        insertDate = "11/16/2009"
        name = 1234
        templateID = 227
        templateType = "Exam"
        templateTypeID = 5
     [56] (Object)#59
        abbreviation = "breast only"
        insertDate = "03/15/2005"
        name = "breast exam"
        templateID = 195
        templateType = "Exam"
        templateTypeID = 5
```

Example of Flex code leading to the Grouping:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid displayItemsExpanded="true" id="gridTemplates">
  <mx:dataProvider>
    <mx:GroupingCollection id="gc" source="{arcTemplates}">
      <mx:Grouping >
        <mx:GroupingField name="templateTypeID" compareFunction="gcSort">
```

GC sort function:

```
public function gcSort(a:Object, b:Object):int{
    return ObjectUtil.stringCompare(String(a.templateTypeID + a.name).toLowerCase(), 
                                    String(b.templateTypeID + b.name).toLowerCase());
}
```

**Problem:** In my AC example there are a few items, items 0, 32 and 56 properly sort and group to their templateTypeID, but item 55 does something weird. It seems to sort/group on the numeric 5 instead of the string "5". Gets stranger. If I change the name property to contain text (so 1234x) it then correctly sorts/groups to the string "5"

**Question:** What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i trust your trace, you see that `name=1234` is written without quote, so it is considered as a `Number`.

When you are doing in your `gcSort` `String(a.templateTypeID + a.name)`, you are in fact this time adding two numbers (`5+1234`) and convert them back to a `String` => `"1239"`.

What you can do is convert first your name into string and then do your concatenation:

```
(a.templateTypeID + a.name.toString()).toLowerCase()
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick, tested your fix and it works fine. Was such a beginner mistake :-( but then this was very early code for me. I think it threw me too that item 32 was grouping/sorting just fine, which is actually rather confusing, but I understand now why.